# How can I update textfields in a dynamically designed widget using API responses in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, textfield

How to update texfield in dynamic design i.e type of widget and question,answers are getting from API response in flutter.I have created dynamic design using API response.but i am not getting unique key added for textfield to update specific items data in a list of widgets.

Comment: You can use [TextEditingController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController-class.html)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.